# How can I have a string of string in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
patientID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
age<-c(25,30,28,52,45,26,36,32)
s<-c("m","w","w","m","w","w","m","w")
diabetes<-c("T1","T2","T2","T3","T1","T2","T1","T1")
status<-c("poor","ïmproved","poor","ïmproved","Excellent","poor","ïmproved","Excellent")
patientenData<-data.frame(patientID,age,diabetes,status,s)
```

and want to write a filter as follows

```
filter<-c(s=="m","age>28","OR",s=="w","age>38")
filter<-paste(filter,collapse="&")
filter<-gsub("&OR&","|",filter)
patientenData<-patientenData[with(patientenData,eval(parse(text=filter))),]
```

The problem is, to be able to execute the last part I need an "string of an string". I mean

```
filter<-c("s=="m"","age>28","OR","s=="w"","age>38")
```

because of `parse` and `eval`. But it is not easily possible. I tried `toString` and `is.character` or `as.character` too but without success. 
Thanks for every hint.

Comment: You can achieve quotations in quotations using either escape characters of mixing your quotation marks. For example: `"And Bob said 'hello' to me. "`

Comment: `filter<-c("s=='m'","age>28","OR","s=='w'","age>38")` works. But I would also consider doing the filter without this text manipulation method

Comment: @PierreLafortune: how? My only concern is the hierarchy of & and | because I am not sure if a&b&c |d&e = (a&b&c) |(d&e)

Answer (score 3):

data.table package is a much better way to go:

```
library(data.table)
patientID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
age<-c(25,30,28,52,45,26,36,32)
s<-c("m","w","w","m","w","w","m","w")
diabetes<-c("T1","T2","T2","T3","T1","T2","T1","T1")
status<-c("poor","ïmproved","poor","ïmproved","Excellent","poor","ïmproved","Excellent")
patientenData<-data.table(patientID,age,diabetes,status,s)
```

As a data.table you can then write a SQL like query

```
filtered<-patientenData[s=='m' & age>28 | s =='w'&age>38]
```

Answer (score 1):

with `subset()` from `{base}`:

```
filtered <- subset(patientenData, s=='m' & age>28 | s =='w' & age>38)
```

with indexing:

```
filtered <- patientenData[with(patientenData, s=='m' & age>28 | s =='w' & age>38), ]
```